# activeElement's child number relative to parent

Tags: javascript

Is there a function in vanilla JS (i.e. not JQuery etc) to determine the `activeElement`'s child number?

I'm currently using this code, but I'd prefer to use `selCell = document.activeElement.childNumber;` (for example) rather than looping through the parent:

```
for(var j = 0; cell = document.activeElement.parentNode.cells[j]; j++)
    if(cell == document.activeElement)
        selCell = j;
```

If any clarification is needed (such as HTML context), ask away!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Does it need to work for any element, or just table cells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table cells keep their own index...

```
selCell = document.activeElement.cellIndex;
```

---

For other element types, a common solution is to start at the current element, and iterate through previous siblings, incrementing a counter every time an element is encountered.

```
var i = 0;

while(elem = elem.previousSibling)
    if (elem.nodeType === 1)
        i++;
```

Comment: Fantastic, thank you @am-not-i-am - I scrolled through the list of options in `document.activeElement.*` in Dreamweaver CS6, and tried a few of the `index` options, but none worked. Strangely, `cellIndex` isn't listed in Dreamweaver!

Comment: @DannyBeckett: You're welcome. FYI, table rows do the same thing with `rowIndex`.

Comment: That [works for logging the index of the cell within its parent `tr`](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/WTgrH/), but is there a way to retrieve the index of the cell within the table as a whole (without using the `rowIndex` and working it out)?

Comment: @DavidThomas: Not that I'm aware of. You'd need to use the `rowIndex` and `cells.length` of the row, and do the math manually.

Comment: Yeah, that was my assumption, when I saw how `cellIndex` worked; but I just thought I'd ask (just in case...).